# JSONP usage - scope or async issue? Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm calling a JSONP service using $.ajax function:

```
    $.ajax({
     url: jsonpURI,
     dataType: "jsonp",
     jsonpCallback: callback,
     success: function () {
        console.log("Success");
     }, error: function (err) {
        console.log("Failed to load external deals feed");
     }
    });
```

The aim is to load in the JSONP just once and store it for use later. It seems that the variable isn't holding the object.

```
function callback(data){
 console.log(data);
} // Returns null
```

I'm thinking it's either a scope issue, or an async issue. Any suggestions on how to use the callback correctly, and have access to the JSONP object globally?

Answer (score 2):

`jsonpcallback` is the [`$.ajax` parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) where you can pass the *name* of global callback function that will be used for [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (if you don't want jQuery to choose one on its own). You don't really need to specify this.

You seem to want to use your callback as the `success` callback. Either pass it as that, call it from your custom success function, or attach it with the [deferred methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

```
$.ajax({
     url: jsonpURI,
     dataType: "jsonp",
     success: callback, // or:
     success: function(data) {
         console.log("Success");
         callback(data);
     }, error: function (err) {
         console.log("Failed to load external deals feed");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even store the return JSONP object in localstorage variable

```
window.localStorage(<key>,<value or object>);
```